# Doesn't work a my code dedicated to sorting

Tags: c

I have some code and some test cases. First case passed, second failed. 
I don't understand what the problem is.

Problem:
You are given N triangles, specifically, their sides a[i], b[i] and c[i]. Print them in the same style but sorted by their areas from the smallest one to the largest one. It is guaranteed that all the areas are different.

I'm using Heron's formula:

```c
    double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
    double area = sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c))
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;

double area(int a, int b, int c)
{
    a = (double) a;
    b = (double) b;
    c = (double) c;

    double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
    return sqrt(p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
}

int compareTringle(const void* left, const void* right){

  double leftArea = area(((triangle *)left)->a, ((triangle *)left)->b,
              ((triangle *)left)->c);
  double rightArea =
      area(((triangle *)right)->a, ((triangle *)right)->b,
           ((triangle *)right)->c);

  if (leftArea > rightArea)
    return 1;
  if (leftArea < rightArea)
    return -1;
  return 0;
}

void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    qsort(tr, n, sizeof(triangle), compareTringle);
}

int main()
{
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
}
sort_by_area(tr, n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
}
return 0;
}
```

```
First test:
    Input:
        3
        7 24 25
        5 12 13
        3 4 5
    Output:
        3 4 5
        5 12 13
        7 24 25
```

It passed

```
Second case: https://pastebin.com/DFBGz2KD
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `(a + b + c) / 2` it always gives you integer division.

Comment: Double comparision in C doesn't work like `if a > b`. You may need to update your leftArea and rightArea comparisons [effectively](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/Howto_compare_floating_point_numbers_in_the_C_programming_language).

Comment: Additionally, adding an `double area;` member to triangle would allow you to compute the area when reading the information and then simply call  `qsort` using a `double` comparison.

Comment: `double p = (a + b + c) / 2.;` is all that is needed, and VALIDATE the returns of `scanf` and `malloc`. Note, remove ALL `a = (double) a;` (that simply tries to store 8-bytes in a 4-byte variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't doing what you want:

```
a = (double) a;
b = (double) b;
c = (double) c;
```

The problem is that the variables `a`, `b`, and `c` are still integers.  So you're converting them to double, then they're being implicitly converted back to integers and stored back as integers.  Then the following doesn't work:

```
double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
```

since `a + b + c` is an integer, so the division is integer division.

You could fix it by doing:

```
double da = a;
double db = b;
double dc = c;
```

and then using `da`, `db`, `dc` in place of `a`, `b`, `c`.

But if you'd rather let the compiler perform the type promotions for you, you can get rid of the assignments and instead just change the assignment to `p` to:

```
double p = (a + b + c) / 2.0;
```

This will add `a`, `b`, and `c` as integers, then convert the result to `double` since it's now dividing by a double constant, `2.0`.

Either way will work.

Answer (score 2):

Tom has given you a good answer to solve your integer promotion problem, but there are a number of of issues just inviting *Undefined Behavior*  and a number of other nits you can clean up.

First, you must *always* validate ALL input. Otherwise, you have no clue whether a *matching* or *input* failure occurred with `scanf` and you are blindly making use of values that will be indeterminate in the case of either failure. Simply validate the return of `scanf`, e.g.

```
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* validate every input */
        fputs ("error: invalid formate - 'n'.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c) != 3) {
            fputs ("error: invalid format - a,b,c.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
```

You must validate *every* allocation (whether using `malloc, calloc` or `realloc`) for the exact same reason. It is not a matter of `"if"` and allocation will fail, it is a matter of `"when"`. Since an allocation failure sets `errno`, your error reporting is a trivial call to `perror`, e.g.

```
    triangle *tr;
    ...
    if (!(tr = malloc (n * sizeof *tr))) {  /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-tr");
        return 1;
    }
```

Nits. In C when you declare a function and leave the parenthesis empty `()` you have specified that the function takes an *unspecified* number of arguments, not zero. To make you declaration of `main()` conforming, you should use:

```
int main (void) {
```

See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1)

There is no need for any of your casts in `area`, simply resolve the integer division problem by adding a `'.'` after the `2` and let default promotions handle the rest, e.g.

```
double area (int a, int b, int c)   /* remove all casts, add '.' after 2 */
{
    double p = (a + b + c) / 2.;
    return sqrt (p*(p-a)*(p-b)*(p-c));
}
```

While you are free to declare the `struct` and `typedef` separately, you can do it in a single declaration as well, e.g.

```
typedef struct {    /* you can simply create the typedef */
    int a, b, c;
} triangle;
```

After you fix your integer division issue, your code will work fine, but you should fix the other issues to make sure you don't run off into *Undefined Behavior* due to a foreseeable input of allocation error. With the integer division fixed, running against your test input will result in:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/triangle_sort_area < dat/triangles_20.txt
22 18 5
31 41 14
20 23 21
54 62 11
26 41 65
58 31 31
20 39 32
26 41 62
44 48 18
23 37 47
53 18 54
28 36 40
31 46 39
33 45 49
57 33 45
28 56 56
41 38 55
55 44 44
48 49 67
58 61 50
```